# API does not return right data in Google Apps Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I'm trying to fetch Wise API to save the exchange rate to Google Sheets, but for some reason the data returned is not correct.

It works in Postman but when I make same request in Google Sheets via Google Apps Script data just don't match.

**curl example from documentation**

```
  https://api.transferwise.com/v3/quotes/ \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <your client credentials token>"
  -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "sourceCurrency": "GBP",
    "targetCurrency": "USD",
    "sourceAmount": null,
    "targetAmount": 110 }'
```

**Response in Postman:**

[image]

**Request in Google Apps Script:**

```
const url = "https://api.transferwise.com/v3/quotes/";
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Bearer + mytoken",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        "followRedirects": true,
        "validateHttpsCertificates": true,
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "payload": JSON.stringify({"\\\"sourceCurrency\\\"":"\\\"EUR\\\"","\\\"targetCurrency\\\"":"\\\"USD\\\"","\\\"sourceAmount\\\"":"null","\\\"targetAmount\\\"":"1000"})
    });

  const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())

    Logger.log("Response code is %s", response.getResponseCode());
    Logger.log(data.rate);
}
```

**Response on console:**

[image]

API is returning "1.0176" instead of "0.98015" and I can't discovery what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Code and logs should be added as text not as images. Once said that the Postman code GET request doesn't exactly match the Google Apps SCript GET request... besides other differences they are using different currencies. Consider to simplify the Google Apps Script payload value, as you are already do using JSON.stringify, pass to it a literal object wrote as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your payload to:

```
 "payload": `{
  "sourceCurrency": "EUR",
  "targetCurrency": "USD",
  "souceAmount": 1000,
  "targetAmount": null 
 }`
```